# How to solve toymoy.com sites opens properly but www.toymoy.com gives error?

Tags: wordpress, web, e-commerce

just put my site in live with google analytics. When I look at the pages page are shown in the browser for http://toymoy.com/ but not for [www.toymoy.com](http://www.toymoy.com) What causes this and how can it be fixed.
Step by Step process are most welcome.

Thanks for your help :)

Note: the site is developed in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics doesn't effect any www redirection.

To make www.toymoy.com from http://toymoy.com go to your wordpress installation folder open *.htaccess* file and find RewriteEngine and replace below code with that.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^toymoy.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.toymoy.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```